# MVC Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am brand new to MVC and have been stuck on a ridiculous error running my first simple test app in vb.net. Googling for hours to no avail. Action error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> BC30451: 'Layout' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

The Razor code failing is simply:

```
@Code 
Layout = Nothing
End Code
```

But I can't get to Viewbag either. All references seem to be in place.

Comment: I believe this is viewstart View. Just comment out the line Layout=Nothing and run

Comment: How does your web.config look like? Probably you are missing a reference there to System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase?

Comment: Commenting out Layout=Nothing definitely does not work. As I said, it will still fail when I reach any ViewBag code. Before that it fails at Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage. I have a reference to System.Web.Mvc in references, imports and in the Web.Config.

Comment: Can you double check that System.Web.Mvc is set to Copy Local = true?

Comment: Can you share your web.config in the views folder? Did you start from a template?